# Can Python task scheduler Luigi detect indirect dependencies?

Tags: python, dependencies, scheduled-tasks, luigi

**Short Version:**

Is there a task scheduler in Python that can do what gmake does? In particular, I need a task scheduler that recursively resolves dependencies. I looked into Luigi, but it seemed only resolve direct dependencies.

**Long version:**

I'm trying to build a workflow that processes a lot of data files in a pre-defined order, the later tasks may directly depend on the output of some ealier tasks, but in turn, the correctness of these outputs relies on even ealier tasks.

For example, let's consider a dependency map like follows:

A <- B <- C

When I request the result from task C, Luigi will automatically schedule B, and then since B depends on A, it will schedule A. So the final run order will be [A, B, C]. Each task will create an offical output file as a sign of successful execution. This is fine for the first run.

Now, suppose that I made a mistake in the input data for task A. Apparently, I need to rerun the whole chain again. However, simply deleting the output file from A won't work. Because Luigi sees the output of B and C, and concludes that the requirement for Task C has been fulfilled, and no runs are needed. I have to delete the output files from *ALL* the tasks that depend on A so they will be run again. In the simple case, I have to delete all the output files from A, B and C, so that Luigi will detect the change made to A.

This is a very unconvenient feature. If I have tens or hundreds of tasks that have rather complicated dependencies on each other, it will be really hard to tell which ones are affected when one of the tasks needs to be re-run. For a task scheduler and has the ability of resolving dependencies, I would expect Luigi to be able to act similar to GNU-Make, where dependencies are checked recursively, and the final target will be rebuilt when one of the deepest source files is changed.

I was wondering if someone can provide some suggestions on this issue. Am I missing some key features in Luigi? Are there other task schedulers that do act as gmake? I'm particularly interested in Python based packages, and would prefer those support Windows.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems possible by overriding the complete method for your tasks. You'd have to apply this all the way down through the dependency graph.

```
def complete(self):
    outputs = self.flatten(self.output())
    if not all(map(lambda output: output.exists(), outputs)):
        return False
    for task in self.flatten(self.requires()):
        if not task.complete():
            for output in outputs:
                if output.exists():
                    output.remove()
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Hi @MattMcKnight, Thanks a lot for pointing out the "complete" method! I'll try this solution. However, I wonder why Luigi is not doing this by default? Using Python for loop to manually resolve the dependencies might not be very efficient, and normal user like me may make mistakes and/or do things sub-optimally. But anyway, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Several corrections are needed for the above code to work. First, the method `flatten` is defined by Luigi, so needs to be called as `self.flatten`. Second, I found it better to reuse the default `complete` method at the end to check the status of the task itself, so I wrote `return super(MyTask, self).complete()`, assuming the inherited class is named `MyTask`. However, I still get a "File already exist" error when running the down stream tasks, because their output files are not deleted. Any idea how to automatically update these output files?

Comment: Apologies for not trying the code, just wanted to give a rough idea of an approach. I suppose in addition to returning `False` from complete, one would have to delete the existing output. The Task.complete() method isn't that sophisticated. https://github.com/spotify/luigi/blob/master/luigi/task.py#L526

Comment: There have been a few requests for similar cleanup type processes. https://github.com/spotify/luigi/issues/595#issuecomment-194323344

Comment: Hi @MattMcKnight, thanks for the update! I found that Luigi LocalTarget has a "remove" method that may be used for removing the file. So, instead of using the os.remove method, I will call the output.remove(). I'll accept this answer, and post my final tested version as well. Thank you very much for your help! :)

Comment: Hi @MattMcKnight, I've asked this question on Luigi's GitHub repository, and someone brought up the effeciency issue. As in the answer right now, the outputs of the current task are tested the *last*, after all the required tasks got checked. This may not be optimal. Could you change the answer to check the current level output first, and then search the higher level dependencies? Also, it would be nice if you can wrap the method in a whole inherited class, and mention that all concrete task classes can be further derived from this modified "base" class.

Comment: By the way, I was thinking if there is a way to scan the task pool only once, and assign a flag to each task. So that when its complete method is called, the status can be easily determined without calling all the deeper tasks' complete method. Right now, the answer has a worst case efficiency of ~O(n!), which can be really slow when n is big. I'll think more about this. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! I've accepted the answer! Thank you for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed this is inconvenient and [d6tflow](https://github.com/d6t/d6tflow) checks all upstream dependencies for completeness to not just the presence of output for TaskC. If you reset TaskA, TaskC will also be incomplete and automatically rerun.

```
# reset TaskA => makes TaskC incomplete
TaskA().invalidate() 
d6tflow.preview(TaskC()) # all tasks pending
```

For further details see full example below and [d6tflow docs](https://d6tflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/control.html#manually-forcing-task-reset-and-rerun).

```
import d6tflow
import pandas as pd

class TaskA(d6tflow.tasks.TaskCachePandas):  # save dataframe in memory

    def run(self):        
        self.save(pd.DataFrame({'a':range(10)})) # quickly save dataframe

class TaskB(d6tflow.tasks.TaskCachePandas):

    def requires(self):
        return TaskA() # define dependency

    def run(self):
        df = self.input().load() # quickly load required data
        df = df*2
        self.save(df)

class TaskC(d6tflow.tasks.TaskCachePandas):

    def requires(self):
        return TaskB()

    def run(self):
        df = self.input().load() 
        df = df*2
        self.save(df)

# Check task dependencies and their execution status
d6tflow.preview(TaskC())
'''
└─--[TaskC-{} (PENDING)]
   └─--[TaskB-{} (PENDING)]
      └─--[TaskA-{} (PENDING)]
'''

# Execute the model training task including dependencies
d6tflow.run(TaskC())

'''
===== Luigi Execution Summary =====

Scheduled 3 tasks of which:
* 3 ran successfully:
    - 1 TaskA()
    - 1 TaskB()
    - 1 TaskC()
'''

# all tasks complete
d6tflow.preview(TaskC())

'''
└─--[TaskC-{} (COMPLETE)]
   └─--[TaskB-{} (COMPLETE)]
      └─--[TaskA-{} (COMPLETE)]
'''

# reset TaskA => makes TaskC incomplete
TaskA().invalidate() 
d6tflow.preview(TaskC())
'''
└─--[TaskC-{} (PENDING)]
   └─--[TaskB-{} (PENDING)]
      └─--[TaskA-{} (PENDING)]
'''
```

Comment: Could you briefly comment on the efficiency of the algorithm the library used to resolve the recursive dependencies? What is the typical size of the task pool this library can handle without a significant/noticeable latency?

Comment: Not sure, it's never been a problem in practice and I've built large-scale ML systems with it. The work happens inside the tasks, the library just coordinates. One user trained 20K ML models.